# How to get Checkbox value in MVC asp.net using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I have Java Script, this create checkbox and I want to get those selected checkbox values using JQuery. In my java script I bind student's subject with checkbox. When student select their own subject, I want to get those subject list. Any solution please....

My Java script is

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function specilizationChange()
    {
        $("#Subjectfield").empty();

        var URL = "/SemesterRegistation/GetSubjects/";
        $.ajax({
            url: URL,
            data: JSON.stringify({ SpecializationID: $("#SpecializationID").val() }),
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {

                for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {

                    $("#Subjectfield").append("<input type='checkbox' name='chksub' id='" + response[i].Subject + "'/><label>" + response[i].SubjectName + " </label>");
                    $("#Subjectfield").append("<input type='hidden' value='false' name='" + response[i].Subject + "' />")
                }
            },
            error: function (reponse) {
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should change your javascript method like as below:

```
function specilizationChange() {

       $("#Subjectfield").remove();

        var URL = "/SemesterRegistation/GetSubjects/";
        $.ajax({
            url: URL,
            data: JSON.stringify({ SpecializationID: $("#SpecializationID").val() }),
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json"
        }).success(function (response) {
                for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {

                    var html = '<li>' +
                                    '<input type="checkbox" name="chksub" class="class" value="' + response[i].Subject + '"/>' +
                                    '<input type="hidden" name="' + response[i].Subject + '" value="false"/>' +
                               '</li>';                     

                   $('#Subjectfield').append(html);
                }
        }).fail(function() {
        });  
    }
```

And then you can connect your each subject id like as below:

```
$('#Subjectfield').on('change', 'input[class]', function () {

        console.log($(this).closest('li').children('input').attr('value'));

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way use common class for checkboxes then use this script to get checked id

```
$("#Subjectfield").append("<input type='checkbox' class='sel_subj' name='chksub' id='Example'/><label>Example</label>");

$('#Subjectfield').on('change','.sel_subj',function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
        alert($(this).attr('id'))
});
```

Comment: When I click  check box this is not giving any alert..Here is my Jquery

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("Subjectfield").on('change', '.sel_subj', function () {
            if($(this).is(':checked'))
                alert($(this).attr('id'))
        })

Comment: @KrishanManjula add class in appending part then use `$("#Subjectfield").on('change','.sel_subj',function(){` include `#`

Comment: I already added that class to appending part..But it is not working...I think this Jquery is not fire when I select chekbox..

Comment: In here "Subjectfield" is div id.....
<div class="editor-field" id="Subjectfield" style="height:200px; overflow:auto"> 
</div>